# how to correctly use the OR operator java

Tags: java

Hi I have been pullıng my hair out over this

I want this program to terminate if the user enters 0 or the running total = 20 exactly.  When I try to compile I get an error:

here is my code - what an I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RunningTotal
{  
       public static void main( String[] args)
       {   
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  

            int current = 1, total = 0;

            System.out.print( "Type in a bunch of values and I'll add them up. ");
            System.out.println( "I'll stop when you type a zero." );

            do
            {
                System.out.print("Value: ");
                current = keyboard.nextInt();
                int newtotal = current + total;
                total = newtotal;
                System.out.println("The total so far is: " + total);
            }  while (current != 0) || (total != 20);

            System.out.println("The final total is: " + total);
        }
}
```

Comment: The condition should be `while ( (current != 0) && (total != 20) )`

Answer (score 2):

You got an error as you placed the brackets incorrectly

Here you have to use `AND` not `OR`.

```
do
{
    System.out.print("Value: ");
    current = keyboard.nextInt();
    int newtotal = current + total;
    total = newtotal;
    System.out.println("The total so far is: " + total);
}  while ((current != 0) && (total != 20));
```

Comment: condition should be OR I guess and not AND

Comment: @Vihar It should be an AND. Remember the De Morgan laws.

Comment: @Vihar Yes, so consider them :)

Comment: De Morgans Law.... right!

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is missing an extra ( ) to wrap the OR conditions (each one needs to be in a bracket)

```
public class RunningTotal
{  
   public static void main( String[] args)
   {   
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  

        int current = 1, total = 0;

        System.out.print( "Type in a bunch of values and I'll add them up.     ");
        System.out.println( "I'll stop when you type a zero." );

        do
        {
            System.out.print("Value: ");
            current = keyboard.nextInt();
            int newtotal = current + total;
            total = newtotal;
            System.out.println("The total so far is: " + total);
        }  while ((current != 0) || (total != 20));

        System.out.println("The final total is: " + total);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

your while line is wrong it should be like this the expression in the while must be in braces () like this while(expression); and not like while(expression)||(expresion);
if you really want to use or this a solution

```
 boolean notFinished = true;
     do
                {
                    System.out.print("Value: ");
                    current = keyboard.nextInt();
                    int newtotal = current + total;
                    total = newtotal;
                    System.out.println("The total so far is: " + total);
                    if (current==0 || total ==20){
 notFinished=false;
                    }
                }  while (notFinished);
```

this is a Simpler Solution this is also correct because of de Morgans Law

```
 while ((current != 0) && (total != 20));
```

this line should also work

```
while(current !=0 && total !=20);
```

Comment: The condition should be `while ( (current != 0) && (total != 20) )`

Comment: @peter.petrov Thanks for the advice didnt noticed it